# How to add different header image for every page?

Tags: wordpress, image, header

i am useing wp version 4.7 and i want to use different images on every page on header kindly tell me is it possible or not? 
client want to be able to upload a different header image for each page within the backend of WP.

Comment: There are like one million possibilities. E.g. use this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-header-images/

Comment: This is not a question related to programming and might also be better suited to [wordpress.stackexchange](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score -1):

there are a lot of Wordpress plugins that allow you to custom your header image for each page as WP Header Images.

Comment: Can you tell name of anyone ?

Comment: and i am talking about background images. not only images.